# How to use docker-java API to connect docker?

Tags: java, docker, boot2docker

I'm new to docker, and I want to use java api to print my docker information. Then I find the Api in this [link](https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java) about docker-java. And I found my boot2docker ip is 196.168.59.103:2376. And I use this command:

```
docker -H tcp://192.168.59.103:2376 version
```

It can succeed and show me this information:

```
Client version: 1.7.0
Client API version: 1.19
Go version (client): go1.4.2
Git commit (client): 0baf609
OS/Arch (client): darwin/amd64
Server version: 1.7.0
Server API version: 1.19
Go version (server): go1.4.2
Git commit (server): 0baf609
OS/Arch (server): linux/amd64
```

Then, I new a maven project in eclipse, and run this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        DockerClient dockerClient = DockerClientBuilder.getInstance("http://192.168.59.103:2376").build();
        Info info = dockerClient.infoCmd().exec();
        System.out.print(info);
    }
```

But, it didn't work at all, and throw the exception about this:

```
The server failed to respond with a valid HTTP response
```

And,I use command curl to connect:

```
curl -v http://192.168.59.103:2376/info
```

It show me information is below:

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 192.168.59.103...
* Connected to 192.168.59.103 (192.168.59.103) port 2376 (#0)
> GET /info HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.37.1
> Host: 192.168.59.103:2376
> Accept: */*
> 

* Connection #0 to host 192.168.59.103 left intact
```

How should I do in this case? I want to use this to show some docker information and do something to docker using java code.
more java exception detail is:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
    at org.glassfish.jersey.apache.connector.ApacheConnector.apply(ApacheConnector.java:513)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$2.call(JerseyInvocation.java:683)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:424)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:679)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:408)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.get(JerseyInvocation.java:308)
    at com.github.dockerjava.jaxrs.InfoCmdExec.execute(InfoCmdExec.java:26)
    at com.github.dockerjava.jaxrs.InfoCmdExec.execute(InfoCmdExec.java:12)
    at com.github.dockerjava.jaxrs.AbstrDockerCmdExec.exec(AbstrDockerCmdExec.java:57)
    at com.github.dockerjava.core.command.AbstrDockerCmd.exec(AbstrDockerCmd.java:29)
    at org.v11.dm.docker.Demo.main(Demo.java:15)
Caused by: org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:188)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:72)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.apache.connector.ApacheConnector.apply(ApacheConnector.java:465)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.apache.http.ProtocolException: The server failed to respond with a valid HTTP response
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:151)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:260)
    at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:161)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.invoke(CPoolProxy.java:138)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy19.receiveResponseHeader(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:271)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:123)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:253)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:194)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:85)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:186)
    ... 16 more
```

Comment: Should that be https?

Comment: @McDowell Do you mean using DockerClientBuilder.getInstance("https://192.168.59.103:2376")? It didn't work. Just throw exception: https protocol is not supported

Answer (score 0):

Your code worked for me.

I have following setup -

1. Docker daemon is running with this command -

   `/usr/bin/docker -d -H fd:// -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375`
2. I am able to curl -

   `curl http://localhost:2375/info`
3. Also able to run your code.

**NOTE**

If you are using boot2docker, please check how daemon is running and is it accepting http request. If it's running with TLSVerify please stop it and run as i mentioned in 1st step.