# How to access docker (v1.9.0) remote rest api in mac os x

Tags: macos, rest, docker

I am trying to access the docker remote rest api but I am not able to access it.

e.g.

```
 $ curl -v https://192.168.99.100:2376/images/json
* About to connect() to 192.168.99.100 port 2376 (#0)
*   Trying 192.168.99.100...
* Adding handle: conn: 0x7f8cd380fe00
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x7f8cd380fe00) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* Connected to 192.168.99.100 (192.168.99.100) port 2376 (#0)
* SSL certificate problem: Invalid certificate chain
* Closing connection 0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: Invalid certificate chain
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.

$ curl -v http://192.168.99.100:2376/images/json
* About to connect() to 192.168.99.100 port 2376 (#0)
*   Trying 192.168.99.100...
* Adding handle: conn: 0x7f9411008c00
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x7f9411008c00) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* Connected to 192.168.99.100 (192.168.99.100) port 2376 (#0)
> GET /images/json HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
> Host: 192.168.99.100:2376
> Accept: */*
>

* Connection #0 to host 192.168.99.100 left intact
```

but if I run the docker command it works:

```
$docker images
REPOSITORY                      TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
subh007/docker_quagga           v1                  fd482b733697        6 months ago        263.5 MB
```

I have also tried to follow the suggestion from [stack post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31264333/how-to-enable-docker-remote-api-rest-in-mac-os-x-with-boot2docker), but it din't work for me, looks like it worked for `boot2docker`. Currently I am using the mac os X (10.9.4).

Following is docker machine details :

```
$ docker-machine  env default
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1"
export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://192.168.99.100:2376"
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH="/Users/subh/.docker/machine/machines/default"
export DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME="default"
# Run this command to configure your shell:
# eval "$(docker-machine env default)"
```

Please let me know if I am missing some understanding.

Answer (score 0):

The new version of CURL uses Apple's secure transport API instead of OpenSSL API. Use the P12 format of certificates. Try this -

```
cd $DOCKER_CERT_PATH
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey key.pem -in cert.pem -CAfile ca.pem -chain -name client-side -out cert.p12 -password pass:mypass
curl https://192.168.99.100:2376/images/json --cert $DOCKER_CERT_PATH/cert.p12 --pass mypass --key $DOCKER_CERT_PATH/key.pem --cacert $DOCKER_CERT_PATH/ca.pem
```

Comment: still I am facing the same issue, I have updated the response in the post.